# React-Native: should I unbind functions when unmounting components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am currently looking to improve my app performances.
Based on this example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.doWork = this.doWork.bind(this);
  }

  doWork() {
    // doing some work here.
    // this.props.dispatch....
  }

  render() {
    return <Text onPress={this.doWork}>Do Some Work</Text>
  }

}
```

Should I unbind function `this.doWork` in `componentWillUnmount()` ?
Is React Native auto unbinding functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to unbind events that is created by you example, a scroll event, or a keyboard show event.

But not native events by native components like `onPress` event by `<Text>` as they will be handled automatically by react when the component is unmounted

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t necessary. Once the instance of the class is garbage collected, so are the bound functions to that instance.